# activecell.text does not respond to text in cell only to data validation selection

Tags: excel, vba, validation

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim val As String
val = ActiveCell.Text
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("$K$4:$K$2000")) Is Nothing Then
            Select Case val
            Case "Yes"
            Call Addcontrol
            Case "No"
            Call Removecontrol
            Case Else
            End Select
    End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

This code only seems to work if I use a data validation list with yes and no, but not if I manually enter the text, why is that? #drivesmecrazy #helpmuchappreciated

Ok I changed my code to:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Unprotectwb
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("GITCscope")) Is Nothing Then
    If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
            Select Case Target.Value
            Case "Yes"
            Call Riskselectsheet
            Case Else
            End Select
    End If
    
Protectwb
Sheets("Scope").Select
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Problem remains, still entering Yes or No directly into the cell apperently does not trigger this macro.

Ok, the answer was too simple, moving the cursor 1 row up after enter did the trick ;-)
Everybody thanks for the valuable input.

Comment: `Target` and `ActiveCell` aren't necessarily the same thing. Then don't use `val` as a variable name as you're shadowing the [`Val`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/val-function) function. Then, use `.Value` instead of `.Text`. Then, what is your question? Do you understand what the `Select Case` is doing?

Comment: Definitely should not be using `ActiveCell`. Change `Select Case val` to `Select Case Target.Value`. Also add `If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub` to the very beginning so that execution proceeds if only one cell has changed.

Comment: I use target to determine the range to check in if val equals yes or no. Changing to value makes no difference. Case works fine if I use a validation list

Comment: The problem is the use of `ActiveCell`. Use `Target`. In other words, see what the output of `Debug.Print ActiveCell.Address` and `Debug.Print Target.Address` is in the Immediate Window. They're not the same.

Answer (score 0):

Jack.
Try changing :
`ActiveCell.Text` to `ActiveCell.Value`

Hope it works. Sometimes even though the cell shows data, this is not text, but a value.

Jorge

Comment: Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Unprotectwb
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("GITCscope")) Is Nothing Then
    If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
            Select Case Target.Value
            Case "Ja"
            Call Riskselectsheet
            Case "Nee"
            Call Riskselectsheet
            Case Else
            End Select
    End If
    
Protectwb
Sheets("Scope").Select
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub